# Max 2 series visible in hightcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using hightcharts.js to generate the chart. I would like to display on the chart up to 2 series of the 3 available. If click hide item on legend, other becomes invisible. How to do it in the function js?

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                backgroundColor: '#c5c5c5'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Profit'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: true
                }
            },

            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                layout: 'vertical',
                y: 60,
                itemStyle: {
                    'color': '#333',
                    'font-size': '18px'
                },
                itemHiddenStyle: {
                    color: '#a6a6a6'
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Win Rate',
                data: [58, 56, 43, 52],
                color: '#0c0c0a'
            },{
                name: 'Yield',
                data: [25, 20, 9, 10],
                color: '#818181'
            }, {
                name: 'Profit',
                data: [143, 115, 39, 45],
                color: '#ff0000'
            }]
        });

        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var series = chart.series;
        //function which will show max 2 items on charts
    });
```

Comment: How will you determine which series becomes invisible? In general, you can use the **legendItemClick** event and check for visibility. - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legendItemClick event lets you control what happens when a series is turned on or off via the legend.  To have them always have one off, turn the other series back on when one is requested to be turned off.

http://jsfiddle.net/zbLmL7u2/

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function() {
        //if the item they clicked on is disabled, don't do anything
        if (!this.visible) return false;
        else {
            // enable any disabled series and then let highcharts do its thing
          for (var i=0;i< this.chart.series.length;i++)
          {
            this.chart.series[i].show();
          }
        }

      }
    }
  },
```